# How to separate magento currency symbol and the number

Tags: magento, checkout

As i found it in the tax > checkout > grandtotal, just wondering how to separate the currency logo and the number in magento order review

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getTotalExclTax()) ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain it with an example ?

Comment: this variable resulting like this $10, and then i need it will be $       10, so from that 2 variable, i shold break become the symbol, and the number, cheers @slimshadddyyy

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getTotalExclTax()) ?>
```

prints the price with cutrrency symbol i.e. **$10**

If you want to separate the price and currency symbol, you can do it like below

```
<?php echo $this->getTotalExclTax(); ?>//Prints Price (10)


<?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(); ?>//Prints Currency Symbol ($)
```